# Propositional logic gates

Tags: logic

I've literally been trying to figure out how to do these for the past few hours. It's becoming really annoying, tedious and just wasting my time. I understand all the symbols, and can do the basics e.g. $p \wedge q$ but when it comes to e.g. $q \vee \neg r$. I know the answers from notes, but I just can't get them right. When it comes to multiple systems I just don't know how the ordering systems is working e.g. which symbol should be applied first. Saying that, I've tried like every way but can't get the answer correct... Could someone please explain to me how these are supposed to be done ?

edited with example
http://vvcap.net/db/MqcYM1_Q0VnU1O39htGl.htp

Comment: Can you give us an example of one you've been having trouble with?

Comment: http://vvcap.net/db/MqcYM1_Q0VnU1O39htGl.htp

Comment: maybe it helps if you add a column for (¬R) and fill out that one first, before trying to do (Q ∨ ¬R)?

Comment: The column for $P \land R$ appears to be incorrect in any case!

Comment: I know, i've got the correct answers wrote down :P but i can't do it myself

Comment: for ¬ ( p ^ r ) what's the ordering system in how you do it ?

Comment: You can use De Morgan's laws for that, OR at the level you are at, make a column for p, one for r and then one for $p \land r$ and then negate that column to get $\lnot (p \land r)$

Comment: How would i use De Morgan's law :P i'm supposed to be using that i could imagine

Comment: I've given two links in the answer below; look at them, in particular, for De Morgan's Law, you can look at the truth tables here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_tables#Logical_NAND

Comment: i love morgans law, it solved my problem :D i really should listen in lectures

Comment: For "draw the truth table for the following propositional formula:" (p∨¬q) ⇒ (p∧r) would the final answer be F,F,T,T,F,F,F,T

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You must first know these three tables:

$$
% outer vertical array of arrays
\begin{array}{c}
% inner horizontal array of arrays
\begin{array}{cc}
% inner array of minimum values
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p \wedge q \\
\hline
t & t & t \\
t & f & f \\
f & t & f \\
f & f & f
\end{array}
&
% inner array of maximum values
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p \vee q \\
\hline
t & t & t\\
t & f & t \\
f & t & t \\
f & f & f
\end{array}
\end{array}\begin{array}{c|c}
p &  \lnot p \\
\hline
t & f \\
t & t 
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

Then do them one at a time and replace them into your equation when needed.

Here is just one row as an example:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & r &\lnot r & p \wedge r & q \vee \lnot r & (p \wedge r) \vee (q \vee \lnot r)  \\
\hline
t & f & t & f & t & f & t
\end{array}$$

Your goal is to reduce the problem to one of the three above; you look at what you have and find the appropriate rows in the original three and you get the answer. It should become a bit more natural after a while and you shouldn't have to refer to the three tables, but when you are starting out, it is helpful!

For more on truth tables, I refer you [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_tables) and for more on De Morgan's Laws, I refer you [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: For "draw the truth table for the following propositional formula:" (p∨¬q) ⇒ (p∧r) would the final answer be F,F,T,T,F,F,F,T